# pop view controller with enabled/open keyboard in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, keyboard

i am trying to implement some chatroom-like view controller (e.g. Messages-app on iPhone), and i would like to keep the keyboard enabled/open when this (chatroom-like) view controller gets dismissed and therefore gets popped from the stack, BUT dismiss it together with the view, i.e. sliding it out of the screen together with the chatroom-view-controller.
For the desired effect, just open the Messages-app on the iPhone, go into one chatroom/conversation, set the focus on the input-textfield so that the keyboard comes up, but then go back to the last view without dismissing the keyboard.
I always get this weird animation that the chatroom-view (-controller) is sliding out of the screen to the right (which is desired), but the keyboard gets dismissed to the bottom of the screen...

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have already tried it with so many versions, from **become/resign first responder** in all the different **view will/did appears**...

My assumption is that it could have something to do with my custom pan gesture recognizer for popping the chatroom-view-controller from the stack of the navigation controller, but neither the docs nor the web contain such issues...

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: @PatJ: well the thing is, i didnt use a lot of explicit code apart from `[myTextfield resignFirstResponder]` in the `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`, but i am going for the suggestion of @Povilas, i havent tried this approach yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to keep your keyboard visible, instead you can make snapshot of chatroom controller right before it being dismissed.

Edit: I just created simple app with navigation controller which pushed controller contains text field. Then on app tried to pop that controller when keyboard is visible. And..all view was dismissed together with keyboard, so your wanted behaviour is given by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I am going to try your suggestion with snapshotting the view before it gets dismissed!
I know that this is the default behavior on the standard navigation controller, but as I mentioned at the end of my question, I have a custom pan gesture recognizer on my navigation controller, and the standard `interactivePopGesture` (or how it is called) is disabled in my code...